# Android change fragments with 3 level list

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I'm beginner in Android. I created a list of the 3 levels of one of the tutorials and now when i click on the city I wants change fragment and get city name, but I have no idea how to do it.

This is MyActivity class:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    switchFragment(new ChooseCity());

}

public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getName());
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment );
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();

}
```

}

This is my fragment with list:

```
public class ChooseCity extends Fragment {

private ArrayList<World> ContinentsArrayList;
private ArrayList<Country> EuropeContry;
private ArrayList<Country> AsianCountry;
private LinearLayout mLinearListView;
boolean isFirstViewClick=false;
boolean isSecondViewClick=false;



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_choose_city, container, false);

}


@Override
public void onStart(){
mLinearListView = (LinearLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);


    ArrayList<City> PolandCity=new ArrayList<City>();
    PolandCity.add(new City("Lodz"));
    PolandCity.add(new City("Warsaw"));
    PolandCity.add(new City("Krakow"));
    PolandCity.add(new City("Poznan"));

    ArrayList<City> EnglandCity=new ArrayList<City>();
    EnglandCity.add(new City("London"));
    EnglandCity.add(new City("Manchester"));

    ArrayList<City> GermanyCity = new ArrayList<City>();
    GermanyCity.add(new City("Monachium"));
    GermanyCity.add(new City("Dortmund"));

    ArrayList<City> JapanCity = new ArrayList<City>();
    JapanCity.add(new City("Tokio"));

    ArrayList<City> ChinaCity = new ArrayList<City>();
    ChinaCity.add(new City("Pekin"));



    /**
     *
     */
    EuropeContry=new ArrayList<Country>();
    AsianCountry=new ArrayList<Country>();
    EuropeContry.add(new Country("Poland", PolandCity));
    EuropeContry.add(new Country("England", EnglandCity));
    EuropeContry.add(new Country("Germany", GermanyCity));
    AsianCountry.add(new Country("Japan", JapanCity));
    AsianCountry.add(new Country("China", ChinaCity));
    /**
     *
     */

    ContinentsArrayList=new ArrayList<World>();
    ContinentsArrayList.add(new World("Europa", EuropeContry));
    ContinentsArrayList.add(new World("Azja", AsianCountry));


    for (int i = 0; i < ContinentsArrayList.size(); i++) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View mLinearView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);

        final TextView mProductName = (TextView) mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        final RelativeLayout mLinearFirstArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linearFirst);
        final ImageView mImageArrowFirst=(ImageView)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.imageFirstArrow);
        final LinearLayout mLinearScrollSecond=(LinearLayout)mLinearView.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll);

        if(isFirstViewClick==false){
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
        }
        else{
            mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
        }

        mLinearFirstArrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if(isFirstViewClick==false){
                    isFirstViewClick=true;
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                }else{
                    isFirstViewClick=false;
                    mImageArrowFirst.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                    mLinearScrollSecond.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });


        final String name = ContinentsArrayList.get(i).getpName();
        mProductName.setText(name);

        /**
         *
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < ContinentsArrayList.get(i).getmCountryList().size(); j++) {

            LayoutInflater inflater2 = null;
            inflater2 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View mLinearView2 = inflater2.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);

            TextView mSubItemName = (TextView) mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
            final RelativeLayout mLinearSecondArrow=(RelativeLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linearSecond);
            final ImageView mImageArrowSecond=(ImageView)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.imageSecondArrow);
            final LinearLayout mLinearScrollThird=(LinearLayout)mLinearView2.findViewById(R.id.linear_scroll_third);

            if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
            }
            else{
                mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
            }

            mLinearSecondArrow.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    if(isSecondViewClick==false){
                        isSecondViewClick=true;
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_down);
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }else{
                        isSecondViewClick=false;
                        mImageArrowSecond.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.arw_lt);
                        mLinearScrollThird.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });


            final String catName = ContinentsArrayList.get(i).getmCountryList().get(j).getCountrytName();
            mSubItemName.setText(catName);
            /**
             *
             */
            for (int k = 0; k < ContinentsArrayList.get(i).getmCountryList().get(j).getmCityArray().size(); k++) {

                LayoutInflater inflater3 = null;
                inflater3 = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View mLinearView3 = inflater3.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);

                TextView tvCityName = (TextView) mLinearView3.findViewById(R.id.textViewCityName);
                final String CityName = ContinentsArrayList.get(i).getmCountryList().get(j).getmCityArray().get(k).getCityName();
                tvCityName.setText(CityName);


                mLinearScrollThird.addView(mLinearView3);

            }

            mLinearScrollSecond.addView(mLinearView2);

        }

        mLinearListView.addView(mLinearView);
    }


    super.onStart();
}
```

}

I now I want to change fragment when I click on city name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not a pretty way to do a list with 3 levels like that, you can use this [library](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/) if you want something better.

otherwise, try to add a clickListener to your **tvCityName**

```
tvCityName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ((MyActivity)getActivity).switchFragment(/*your new fragment*/);
        } 
    });
```

Comment: I added this code, but when I click on city, I have a crash application and application is closed.